# VBA "Application defined or object defined error "

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to use the excel formula sum in VBA and always got this error "Application-defined or object defined error". I used the same one in my other module and it works.

```
For nCol = 4 To 15
  Worksheets("Per individual Per Month").Cells(RowMark, nCol) = Application.Sum(Range(Worksheets("Resource Allocation Schedule").Cells(RowMark + 7, ColStart), Worksheets("Resource Allocation Schedule").Cells(RowMark + 7, ColEnd)))
  ColStart = ColStart + ColCount
  ColEnd = ColEnd + ColCount
Next nCol
```

Comment: You need to qualify the `Range` call immediately after `Sum(`.  It implicitly references the `ActiveSheet` - this fails if the `ActiveSheet` isn't "Resource Allocation Schedule".

Comment: I changed it to     Worksheets("Per individual Per Month").Cells(RowMark, nCol) = Application.Sum(Range(Worksheets("Resource Allocation Schedule").Cells(RowMark + 7, ColStart), Worksheets("Resource Allocation Schedule").Cells(RowMark + 7, ColEnd)))     and still does not work

Comment: That's exactly what it was before.  It *should* be `... = Application.Sum(Worksheets("Resource Allocation Schedule").Range( ...`, although you should do yourself a favor and either put that in a `With` block or get a Worksheet variable for `Worksheets("Resource Allocation Schedule")`.