# application define or object define error (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, object

I have read the following : [VBA "Application defined or object defined error "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682317/vba-application-defined-or-object-defined-error)

However I can't seem to link it to my problem, even if it looks similar. Here is my code:

```
If Range("What").Value <> "New Entry" Then
    current = 2
    Updated = 3
    For coll = 1 To 49
    'Do While current <> Updated
        If Sheets("GoodDBData").Range(current, coll).Value <> Sheets("GoodDBData").Range(Updated, coll).Value Then
            Base.Range("Changes_Made") = "Yes"
    '        coll = coll + 1
        End If
    'Loop
    Next
End If
```

I basically want to know if the user change anything in current. Basically current and Update or initially the same however if the user make some changes it will appear in current only. Hence when the user is done, if current is different then Update then I want YES in range changes_made.

Anyone know why I get the application define or object define error?
Thanks

Comment: Which line of code is triggering the error?

Comment: Also I don't know if I should be using the Do While - Loop command or the For - Next command

Comment: @CindyMeister sorry forgot to mention it. The error occurs at the If statement.

Comment: Cells(row,col) versus Range("A1")... different syntax.  Swap Range to Cells and you should get through that section.  Verify what you're trying to change inside of the if-statement, too.  *Base.Range("Changes_Made") = "Yes"* doesn' tlook correct, either.

Comment: @Cyril awesome!! It works like a charm :-) BTW Base. was define earlier in the code. I forgot to add that information with this example. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @ValS Thanks for the heads up on Base; I was more focused on the format for Range() = "Yes" rather than Range().Value = "Yes", which will work either way, but still looks odd as you're not clearly stating what is occurring.

Comment: @ValS post-script... if you can self-answer so this post can be closed and not linger, that would be appreciated!